# Use function as react hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, reactn

I wanted to use a function as a react hook to wrap fetch requests to an API.

My current hook:

```
export function useAPI(url, options={}) {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useGlobal('auth');
    const [call, setCall] = useState(undefined);

    const apiFetch = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(url, {
            ...options,
        });
        if (!res.ok)
            throw await res.json();
        return await res.json();
    };

    function fetchFunction() {
        fetch(url, {
            ...options,
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // Only set function if undefined, to prevent setting unnecessarily
        if (call === undefined) {
            setCall(fetchFunction);
            //setCall(apiFetch);
        }

    }, [auth]);

    return call
}
```

That way, in a react function, I could do the following...

```
export default function LayoutDash(props) {
    const fetchData = useAPI('/api/groups/mine/'); // should return a function

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData(); // call API on mount
    }, []);

    render(...stuff);
}
```

But it seems react isn't able to use functions in hooks like that.  If I set `call` to  `fetchFunction`, it returns `undefined`.  If I set it to `apiFetch`, it executes and returns a promise instead of a function that I can call when I want to in the other component.

I initially went for react hooks because I can't use `useGlobal` outside react components/hooks.  And I would need to have access to the `reactn` global variable `auth` to check if the access token is expired.

So what would be the best way to go about this?  The end goal is being able to pass `(url, options)` to a function that will be a wrapper to a fetch request.  (It checks if `auth.access` is expired, and if so, obtains a new access token first, then does the api call, otherwise it just does the API call).  If there's another way I should go about this other than react hooks, I'd like to know.

Comment: Just spitballing here, I'm only about 50% on it, and I have to get to work, so I won't post it as an answer: https://pastebin.com/k9wiFQ6s  May or may not be helpful. :-)

Comment: you can refer to [useDispatch](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/hooks/useDispatch.js) hook in `react-redux`.

Comment: @JosephD. I don't want to use redux.  The point of using reactn was to avoid using redux.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder so is that to be in some random high-level react component, or as a hook?

Comment: @cclloyd i only mentioned "refer" not use. :) perhaps a context-driven switch is helpful.

Comment: @cclloyd - As far as I know, hooks are just functions. No, I wouldn't think of it as a HOC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting your function into `useState`, consider using `useCallback`. Your code would look something like this:

```
export function useAPI(url, options={}) {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useGlobal('auth');

    function fetchFunction() {
        fetch(url, {
            ...options,
        });
    }

    const call = useCallback(fetchFunction, [auth]);


    const apiFetch = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(url, {
            ...options,
        });
        if (!res.ok)
            throw await res.json();
        return await res.json();
    };

    return call
}
```

The returned function is recreated whenever `auth` changes, therefore somewhat mimicking what you tried to do with `useEffect`

Comment: Thanks.  My solution ended up being this.  Calling `useAPI()` returns a callback which is essentially a wrapped `fetch` function.